# How to use EventBus just for first time in Android

Tags: java, android, greenrobot-eventbus-3.0

In my application i have 2 `activity`.**`Activity` A** and **`Activity` B**.
For show **`Activity` B** users should go to from **`Activity` A**.
In **`activity` B** i have one `button` and i want when click on this `button` `finish` **Activity B** and call one method into **Activity A**.
**For this work i write below code :**

```
       baseDialog_positiveBtn.setOnClickListener(v -> {
            EventBus.getDefault().postSticky(new BuyPremiumUserEvent(true));
            finish();
        });
```

**And for call method into `Activity` A i write below code :**

```
@Subscribe(sticky = true, threadMode = ThreadMode.MAIN)
public void onBuyPremium(final BuyPremiumUserEvent event) {
    clickedOnBuyPremium = event.isClickOnBuyPremium();
    Log.e("clickedOnBuyPremium", "Event : " + clickedOnBuyPremium);
    if (AppConstant.getInstance().isPackageInstalled(AppConstant.BAZAAR_PAYMENT_PACKAGE, packageManager)) {
        initBazaarUserRegistered();
    } else {
        AppConstant.getInstance().showMessage(activity, getString(R.string.errorTitle),
                getString(R.string.notInstalledBazaar), R.color.catRedColor);
    }
}
```

When click on `Button`, call above method!
But when click on `Button`, call **Activity A** methods always! 
**My mean is :** after click on `button`, even go to **`Activity` C , E** and more ... and when click on back `button` for go to **`Activity` A** again call above method of **`Activity` A**.
I want call above method just when click on `button` from **`Activity` B**, not always!

How can i fix it?

Comment: Please. Don't beg for an answer.

Comment: @Matthijs I removed it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I correctly understood your situation - you have a button in one activity that initiates an eventBus event, and a second activity-subscriber to this event.

And after button is clicked, you run some registration wizard on another activity, but your problem is that this subscribed method called on other events too, that you don't want to handle in a such way. Is this correct?

Actually, I don't see a point to use eventBus in a such case. If you just want to show `Activity B` from `Activity A`, when button is clicked, then just show your activity using Intent instance:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, ActivityB.class)
startActivity(intent)
```

I could misunderstand you. Can you add more details about your situation?

If you need to use eventBus, then maybe your multiple calls of subscribed events is the cause of making event `sticky`.
Try the same with usual events:

```
 baseDialog_positiveBtn.setOnClickListener(v -> {
            EventBus.getDefault().post(new BuyPremiumUserEvent(true));
            finish();
        });
```

And handle them without sticky flag:

```
@Subscribe(threadMode = ThreadMode.MAIN)
public void onBuyPremium(final BuyPremiumUserEvent event) {
  //...
}
```

Comment: Thanks dear, but when remove sticky option, then not call method from Activity A !!!

Comment: thanks dea. can you send to me your skype image? find me 2 users with you uralniti ID